# Is there any way in LLRP to configure antenna switches?

Tags: rfid, llrp

Rfid Readers perform switches between antennas while using multiple antennas. Reader runs one antenna while others sleeping and switches one by one. It makes it fast so running one antenna at a time doesn't matter. According to my observations, the time for every switch is 1 second.
(After sometime I realised this 1 second is only for Motorola FX7500. Most other readers do it the right way, light fast like in miliseconds)

That is what I know so far.

Now, in my specific application I need this procedure to run faster, like 200ms instead of 1s.

Is this value changeable? If so, which message and parameter in LLRP can modify this value?

Comment: switch between antennas in 1 sec is not right. It has to be light fast like milliseconds. Usually reader will switch between antennas by itself unless you reinitialize it every time you want to read tags.

Comment: @ADOConnection thanks for the comment. You are right, most readers do it the way you said. Actually I figured that the problem was with Motorola FX7500. I don't know why but only in this model, default value of switch is 1 second. Then I discovered Motorola provides vendor specific settings via custom extension fields of LLRP. So the problem is solved for me. By usings this custom params, I could adjust switch time to any amount I want, before any read operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the 1 second problem is with MotorolaFX7500 reader. By examining LLRP messages that Motorola's own library generates between FC7500, I discovered there are vendor specific parameters that can be used via custom extensions fields of LLRP. These params and settings can be found in Motorola Readers' software guide. This switch time is one of these vendor specific parameters, it's not a parameter of generic LLRP. A piece of code generating LLRP message including the custom extension with the proper format, solved my issue.

Comment: requested by Andy: I realise this is an old post, but is there an actual resolution that can be posted. I am happy for Safa that he has found a resolution to this behaviour, but a detailed set of steps to effect a resolution would be very welcome!